# XML response to an express API

Tags: json, node.js, xml, express

I have a node js program, which uses the express framework. What happens, is a POST request is made using Postman to my API, and I deal with the request as required (which works great).

However, I want send back an XML response to the API call. So doing some digging online, I have found this library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml

I tried to adapt it to my code, so I need to convert the following json object into an XML response:

```
var responseJson = [{
   "methodResponse": {
      "params": {
         "param": {
            "value": {
               "struct": {
                  "member": [
                     {
                        "name": "myValue",
                        "value": {
                           "string": "hi"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}];
```

And then in the response I do the following:

```
        res.header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        res.send(xml(responseXml, true));
```

However this only returns:

```
<methodResponse/>
```

and nothing else in the Postman response.

Any idea what happened to the rest and why only one line is returned? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put square brackets around your objects.

```
const data = [{
   "methodResponse": [{
      "params": [{
         "param": [{
            "value": [{
               "struct": [{
                  "member": [{
                      "name": "myValue",
                  },{
                      "value": [{
                         "string": "hi"
                      }]
                  }]
               }]
            }]
         }]
      }]
   }]
}];
```

Which will produce:
`<methodResponse><params><param><value><struct><member><name>myValue</name><value><string>hi</string></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodResponse>`

Comment: oh... why are the square brackets needed?

Comment: Updated my answer to fix the member object. I'm not too familiar with xml so not 100% but my guess is that the elements aren't unique like json objects.